# JMX and different class loaders

Tags: jvm, classloader, jmx, javaagents

My project is multi-module and is structured in this way:

- common (JMX MBean interfaces).
- agent (JMX MBean implementations and instrumentation code - here I register the MBeans)
- plugin (here I "ask" for registered MBeans)

The problem is the plugin part uses a different classloader than the agent. Thus I receive

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.github.lppedd.jmx.FeaturesMBean$Feature cannot be cast to class com.github.lppedd.jmx.FeaturesMBean$Feature
    (com.github.lppedd.jmx.FeaturesMBean$Feature is in unnamed module of loader 'app';
     com.github.lppedd.jmx.FeaturesMBean$Feature is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @35962a94)
```

The incriminated MBean is

```
public interface FeaturesMBean {
  List<Feature> availableFeatures();

  class Feature implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final String name;
    public final String description;

    public Feature(final String name, final String description) {
      this.name = name;
      this.description = description;
    }
  }
}
```

How should I deal with this issue?

Comment: Well, I'm going crazy. Still haven't found a solution.

Comment: You cannot cast an instance of `X` loaded by class loader `A` to `X` loaded by class loader `B`. This seems to be what is happening here. Without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the situation, I can only speculate about why this might occur. You mentioned instrumentation and Java agents. How exactly are you applying the latter two? Which instrumentation tool are you using? Are you putting your Java agent on the command line or attaching it during runtime?